# Npm run dev no funciona

Tags: npm

Estoy usando postman para ver las peticiones, cuando quiero iniciar la aplicación con npm run dev, no lo termina de cargar. Me paso anteriormente, borre el package-log.json y funciono, pero cuando lo quise usar despues, dejo de andar nuevamente.

Me sale asi en la terminal

```
npm run dev

> backend-fundamental@1.0.0 dev
> nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.15
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
```

Y asi esta package.json

```
"main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
```

Al no enviarlo, Postman me da este error

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4000
```

Comment: ¿Tu aplicación corre en el puerto 4000? por que según tu terminal no hay ningún error, puedes agregar el código del archivo server.js

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde sé, `npm run dev` compila lo relacionado a JS en modo desarrollador (mostrar errores cuando ocurran) y `npm run prod` para cuando tienes todo OK y subes a producción...

Quizás lo que necesitas, para que inicie el servidor sea `npm run serve` para probar que la solución funcione como corresponde.

Comment: Hola Aoryu! Me fije con npm run serve y me salen errores, toma el server como script. Anteriormente use npm run dev y me daba las peticiones con error o con la solucion todo bien